# Why is my Web Application not using AppPoolIdentity to log in to SQL Server on same machine?

Tags: sql-server, security, iis

**Basic Problem:**

I have a web application that accesses a SQL Server database on the same machine. The web app runs under its own app pool - let us call it `MyAppPool`. If I goto advanced settings in IIS Manager, I can see that `MyAppPool` runs under `ApplicationPoolIdentity`. When I make requests to the web app, I can open task manager and verify that the username of `w3wp.exe` is `MyAppPool`. In SQL Server, I have added a Windows User `IIS AppPool\MyAppPool` and given it necessary permissions to read from db. The problem is that I am getting a login failed for `DOMAIN\MACHINE$` when a logon is attempted to SQL Server. Its beyond me. Why is the app not logging on as `IIS AppPool\MyAppPool`?

**Details:**

I know variants of this question have been asked elsewhere, but I am really stuck without a solution. I experimented adding a `<identity impersonate="true" />` to the `web.config`. If I do this, I get a login failed for `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR`. I have tried accessing the web app from the machine on which it is hosted and get same login error. I am running IIS8, Windows Server 2012, and SQL Server 2012.

Closest question I could find is [Why is my MVC app trying to log into my DB as my machine, and not as the App Pool identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870158/why-is-my-mvc-app-trying-to-log-into-my-db-as-my-machine-and-not-as-the-app-poo), and the solutions provided do not work. I cannot change Integrated Security to be false (I had this thing running in the past). Quoting https://stackoverflow.com/a/15145488/147530:

> ApplicationPoolIdentity uses IIS AppPool\ApplicationPool for local
>   access, but DOMAIN\MACHINE-NAME$ for remote access

sounds reasonable. Question is why is `ApplicationPoolIdentity` not using `IIS AppPool\MyAppPool` identity when db is hosted on same machine??

Quoting another SO post, [IIS application using application pool identity loses primary token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686186/iis-application-using-application-pool-identity-loses-primary-token):

> This application also connects to a SQL Server database using
>   Integrated Security=true in the connection string. If the database is
>   local, then we see that IIS APPPOOL\OurAppPoolName is used to connect
>   to the database; if the database is remote, then the machine account
>   OURDOMAIN\ourwebserver$ is used.

This is the behavior I want, but not getting it, and that is what I am asking in this question - I don't want to give permissions to `DOMAIN\MACHINE-NAME$` to log onto SQL Server. Quoting https://stackoverflow.com/a/15445280/147530:

> I think that's a bad idea, however, because it authorizes any program
>   running as NetworkService to access the database - not just your web
>   applications.

I tried one more thing, which was to enable Windows Authentication on IIS8 using this link http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-85/installing-iis-85-on-windows-server-2012-r2#ModulesinIIS85 but this has also not solved the problem.

Comment: 1) Which IIS?  2) In "MyAppPool", have you set the app pool to run under a specific identity?  By default, it runs under LocalSystem.  See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0/8853386#8853386

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed this problem. In SSMS, there is a path `machine -> security -> logins` which contains users who can log onto the machine. I had not added the `apppool` to this list. I had only added the `apppool` to `machine -> databases -> my database -> security -> users`